# Question about Relative Clauses

Tags: relative-clauses

Can you suggest me if there are any grammar mistakes in below sentence?

"I would like to live **where** there are many people (who) speaks English."

Comment: A plural subject takes a plural verb. So it should be "speak".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to live where there are many people **who speak** English.

**Speak** needs to be singular to go with **many people**, otherwise your sentence is correct and understandable.

Comment: Did you mean *plural*?